# azure application gateway alert automation

Tags: azure-powershell

I need a PowerShell script to trigger an alert whenever azure application gateway backend health turn to red. I have 2 subscriptions, under this, we have around 150+ Application Gateway provisioned. so the script should be reusable across all the subscription. it would be great, if any sample script available for the reference.

Thanks
Suri

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
Get-AzureRMApplicationGatewayBackendHealth
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/get-azurermapplicationgatewaybackendhealth?view=azurermps-6.13.0

With this command, you can create a runbook inside an automation account, and if the output of the command is a specific value, it can trigger an alert. Spending a few minutes on google shows you how to combine these techniques ;)